# Extension methods and static methods mismatch prototype matching in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, static

Having encountered a more advanced collision problem of extension and static methods I exemplified and simplified some code to:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    static class EM
    {
        public static string To(this object o)
        {
            return o.GetType().ToString();
        }
    }
    class A
    {
        public static string To() { return "Test.A"; }
    }
    class B { }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            object o = null;
            o.To();
            B b = null;
            b.To();
            A a = null;
            a.To();
            A.To();
        }
    }
}
```

I got myself suprised when the .NET compilers, ranging from 3.x to 4.y failed to resolve which method should be called in the line where "`a.To();`" appears. Of course, I paraphrased the compiler but that's what the error message can be brought to (literally "`Member 'Test.A.To()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`").

I am posting this for not going into details of why the compiler alerts a programmer (already know the rules) but more to boost a discussion in what would be a near or final resolve to the problem of this certain kind (take into account inheritance) ahead of Microsoft, where a human can tell the extension/static method call matches easily, whereas the compiler even does not supply the exact programmer's mistake description or a hint.

Looking forward to hearing from 'stackoverflowers'.

Comment: You say it failed on `a.To()`, but the error message you quote says `A.To()`.  Which did you mean?

Comment: @Shymep - You're right -- please disregard my previous comment.

Comment: But this isn't even related to extension methods is it. You'll get the same error message if you try to call any static method using a reference to an instance. The presence of an extension method should not suddenly change the behavior of the type itself.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen but one could reasonably expect the extension method to be selected if one thinks (incorrectly, but reasonably) that the static method is not an "applicable candidate" for the purposes of overload resolution.  It certainly seems reasonable to me that a method that *can't legally be called in a given context* would not be considered in the candidate set for overload resolution.  Even Eric Lippert calls the rules "confusing".

Comment: @phoog: I'm not saying that it isn't confusing and I agree Eric did a much better job explaining this than I did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, your "question" is explicitly a call for discussion. It will therefore be closed, because a call for discussion is not a question. StackOverflow is not a discussion site; there are any number of forums you can use to have a discussion. This is a good place to ask a question.

To clarify the situation: what is happening here is:

- overload resolution is determining that the call `a.To()` has an *applicable candidate* in the form of the static method.
- the fact that the method is static but the receiver is an instance does not make the candidate *inapplicable*. Rather, it makes it *an error for overload resolution to choose it as the best applicable candidate.*
- Extension methods are not checked at all unless *there was no applicable candidate*. There *was* an applicable candidate, albeit an illegal one, so extension methods are not checked.

I agree that this is a bit weird, but the analysis is both correct and desirable. The language designers must decide what is more likely: that the caller intended to call the static method but mis-typed "a" for "A", or that the caller intended to call some *completely different* method that might extend some type compatible with "a". The safer assumption is the former, and therefore we give an error.

I understand that some people might find this analysis somewhat weird. It is somewhat weird, but it does make sense.  If you think these rules are arcane and confusing, you're right; this is what happens when you bolt on new rules to an existing algorithm over a period of more than a decade.

Overload resolution in C# was originally designed to handle a very simple language; "params" was the most complicated part of overload resolution. it now must handle generics, type inference, extension methods, dynamic, and named and optional arguments.  All those changes have severely stressed the overload resolution algorithm because every time a new feature is added we must ensure that the old features continue to work just the same.

Regarding your specific situation: if it hurts when you do that then *do not do that*. It is a very bad idea to make static, instance and extension methods that have the same name. They are unlikely to do *the same thing*, so do not make them have *the same name*.

> the compiler even does not supply the exact programmer's mistake description or a hint.

Nonsense. The compiler tells you exactly what is wrong: overload resolution chose a static method, and you called it with an instance as the receiver. That's the error in the program, and that's the error that is reported.

Comment: With the recent C# compiler this has been approved towards my thinking from years back on and now you can call an extension method that has identical signature as the static one. I wonder what has changed in the language itself that made your reasoning invalid.